# Whenever I try having 2 incophotos I gives back an error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I am writing a python script and I have 2 windows and I want to assign 2 iconphotos, (1 4 each), But I keep getting the following Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\Coding\PythonRenderEngine.py", line 21, in <module>
    inwin.iconphoto(False, inwinIcon)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.2800.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2156, in wm_iconphoto
    self.tk.call('wm', 'iconphoto', self._w, *args)
_tkinter.TclError: can't use "pyimage2" as iconphoto: not a photo image
```

My code seems to be fine but I can't figure this out.
My code:

```
from tkinter import *

#dimensions
WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 600
MIDX = WIDTH/2
MIDY = HEIGHT/2

#Graphics window
gphcs = Tk()
gphcs.title("Snot")
winIcon = PhotoImage(file="D:\Coding\images\Spyglass.png")
gphcs.iconphoto(False, winIcon)
c = Canvas(gphcs, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="blue")
c.pack()

#Input window
inwin = Tk()
inwin.title("Input field")
inwinIcon = PhotoImage("D:\Coding\images\sred-star.png")
inwin.iconphoto(False, inwinIcon)
inc = Canvas(inwin, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg="#891233")
inc.pack()

#Closing
gphcs.mainloop()
inwin.mainloop()
```

Hope you can help!

I tried having 2 windows with individual iconphotos (this is the only method that I can rely on) But I keep getting an error instead of having 2 windows with a different icon.
Please Can you help???

Comment: `this is the only method that I can rely on` What do you mean by this?

Comment: It is because you have two instances of `Tk()`.

Comment: @ryanwebjackson This is the only method I r=can rely on because I either couldn't figure out other methods or they just wouldn't work.

Comment: @acw1668 I need to have this other window open to edit what is in the other window

Comment: Use `Toplevel` instead of `Tk` for windows other than the main/root window.